# Changing Label in Loop C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have created a for loop, and I wanted to add random text, loaded in from an array, to a different label each time the loop runs through. I have all the labels added to my form, called lbl1, lbl2, lbl3 etc.

```
Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            int randomtext = r.Next(0, mytext.GetLength(0)); //choosing random element of array to be added to label
            //this is where I want to add the text to a random label
        }
```

How can I add the text to a random label each time? Would I need to create an array or list of some kind? I was hoping there would be some way of just adding i as the suffix of the variable name each time. Sorry if this is obvious, I am new to C#.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this Windows forms (desktop app), WPF, MVC or Web Forms?

Comment: I'm assuming he is on the desktop. So probably WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this depending on which framework you are using.

In Windows Forms you can use Controls["lbl1"] for instance, so in your case you would write the loop as follows:

```
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
   var randomtext = r.Next(0, mytext.GetLength(0)); //choosing random element of array to be added to label
   var label = (Label)Controls["lbl"+i];
   label.Text = randomtext;
}
```

Or something like that (I can't remember the exact Api for Windows Forms).

On WPF you would use the `FindName` method instead. The container control has this method.

Most other frameworks should have similar methods. In the worst case you could use reflection:

```
var label = (Label)this.GetType().GetProperty("lbl" + i).GetValue(this, null);
```

Comment: Thanks you for the help, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I am creating a Windows Form for Desktop

Answer (score 0):

```
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        int randomtext = r.Next(0, mytext.GetLength(0)); //choosing random element of array to be added to label
        var randomLblIndx = r.Next(1,5);// I am assuming you have 4 lablels only
        var lbl = (Label)this.Controls[lbl + randomLblIndx.ToString()];
        lbl.Text = myarrayOfText[randomtext];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows Forms, there is a property called `Controls` in each Form (or Component) you create. 
This property is a collection of type `ControlCollection` and has a function called `Find`, which allows you to find for a specific control by it's name.

So, you can do something like this:

```
    const labelProfix = "lbl";
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        var randomNumber = r.Next(0, mytext.GetLength(0));
        var label = (Label)Controls.Find(labelPrefix + randomNumber.ToString(), false).First();
        label.Text = "My text";
    }
```

Note that `Find()` return an Array (the name can be ambiguous), so we use the extension method `First()` of `System.Linq;` to get the first element. Besides, thanks to `First()`, that line of code will throw an exception if it doesn't find any control with the name we passed, so you can know if  code wrong without getting `NullReferenceExceptions`